# Is it possible to bump or promote an edited question to get more eyes on it?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I made [my closed question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220264/which-sci-fi-universe-has-the-most-realistic-treatment-of-acausal-phenomena) more clear per recommendations and would like some votes. How, if at all, can the edits be promoted or bumped for a new audience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edits bump posts the front page, however, if a post has a score of -4 or less it won't show on the homepage (to clarify it will still show on the tag page). On top of that a closed question will also go to the reopen queue on the first body edit after closure. Unfortunately for yourself this question is at a score of -5. The question was bumped to the [reopen queue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/154198) with your latest edit. After consideration I voted to leave it closed though. It's not 100% clear what you're asking, is pretty opinion based and is even somewhat off topic for asking about the real world.

That really only leaves you with a handful of options:

1. **Ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe):** You can ask why it is closed in chat, how to improve it, for people to review it etc. etc. There's usually someone around, even if lurking, that might be able to help you.
2. **Ask on meta:** Like in chat you can ask how to improve it or even ask to get it reopened and someone is sure to either explain why it shouldn't be reopened or what needs to be done.
3. You *could* ping commenters on the question and let them know you've addressed some of the issues they've raised. However, use some caution here, don't over ping someone or bug them and don't ping bunches at once i.e. don't "spam" people with pings.
4. At 250 reputation you will be able to vote to reopen your own posts which will send it to the reopen queue to get eyes on it.

Aside from those option I'm not sure there really is anything else you can do.

---

On a side note I'm aware your question is more asking how to get more eyes on a question to review it to see if it need reopening. However, your title *"Is it possible to bump or promote an edit to get more eyes on it?"* isn't really a thing. You can get more eyes on a post but not really on an edit (unless you link the revision of something like that).

Comment: Interesting distinction that last part. “More eyes on an edit but not on a post.” When someone sees my question, what do they see? I can’t find any examples of edits for review - sort of flying blind here

Comment: @VogonPoet My wording is perhaps not the best. My point was users see the current revision of the post and don't see what the edit actually changed unless they click through to the revision.

Comment: [250 reputation is enough](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) to cast close/reopen votes on *your own* questions. Also, "ping[ing] bunches at once" is actually impossible, as the system only allows one @-ping per comment. Just minor nitpicks :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ah was not aware of that and I meant multiple comments not necessarily all in one as I knew of that limitation.